# Could not load file or assembly 'Twilio, Version=5.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a local project in asp.net core 2.1 and i am trying to install Twilio added via Nuget.

nuget install successfully and build successfully, but when I am sending a message from admin side 
in Twilio it displays error

[image: getting this issue while sending a message]

I have tried with different versions but still getting the same issue

Comment: have you checked your project references? Is it referenced there?

Comment: @Sumitraj, yeah it's there

Comment: I am not sure if it will work but try deleting your `obj` and `bin` folder and rebuild the project. If it still doesn't work can you post snapshot of your project references?

Comment: ok sure I will check and inform you.

Comment: I have worked as per your comments  still not working, 
containing snap please have a look
http://prntscr.com/k97gho